# Taking lot of time for execution while using ddply()

Tags: r

Am using `ddply()` for one of my data.frame which has 3527934 objects with 29 variables in R studio. While execution it is taking lot of time incense more than 2hrs. Is there any alternate way / function to elapse this performance in time.

I have observed some of the links but am not able to figure out the apt solution.

sample code:

> `ForwardQ<-ddply(a,c("ID","SM","SY"),summarise,QS=sum(QS),EBLP=sum(EBLPrice),NSV=sum(NS_Value),NIV=sum(Net_Invoice_Value),Standard_COGS=sum(Standard_Cost_Of_Goods_Sold),Standard_Profit=sum(Standard_Profit),Ship_Through_Price_Diff=sum(Ship_Through_Price_Diff),Ship_through_POR=sum(Ship_Through_POR))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try with `dplyr` i.e. `library(dplyr); a %>% group_by(ID, SM, SY) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), columnIndex)`  where `columnIndex` is either the numeric index of columns to be `sum`med

Comment: Thank you akrun for prompt response. Where were you... after a long time you are in the stackoverflow

Comment: No problem.  I think I am visiting SO almost everyday.  Perhaps, we visited at different times.

Comment: i have used the above stated query as MUS1<-MUS %>%
group_by("ID", "SM", "SY") %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum),cQS,EBLP,NSV,NIV,SCOGS,SP,STP_Diff,ST_POR)) am getting only one record could you please help me to get all records after execution

Comment: How many different combinations are there for the grouping variables?  Can you try `dplyr::summarise_each(funs(`

Comment: I have used select(all column names) it worked fine for me :)

Comment: Glad to know that it worked